# registration form using Javascript and Php with MySql Database

Tags: javascript, php, database, mysqli

I'm having problem with the registration for my website.

If I fill out the username field, and leave the others blank, no error-alerts are shown, it just saves the username to the database. There is supposed to be validation, like checking if the age is below 18, but I can't figure out where the error is.

***register.php (javascript code & php code here):***

```
<html>
    <center><h1>Register Below</h1></center>


        <body>
        <br/>
    <script>
        function getText()
        {
            boolean sub = true;
            var name = document.getElementById("t1").value;
            if(name.length < 8 || name.length > 50)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid Username, must be 8 - 10 characters!")
                document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML="*";
            }
            else
            {                   
                document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = name;

            }

            var pass = document.getElementById("t2").value;
            if(pass.length < 8 || pass.length > 50)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid Password, must be 8 - 10 characters!")
                document.getElementById("sample2").innerHTML="*";
            }
            else
            {                   

                sub=true;
            }

            var rpass = document.getElementById("t3").value;
            if(rpass!=pass)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Password dont match!")
                document.getElementById("sample3").innerHTML="*";
            }
            else
            {   
                sub=true;
            }

            var fname = document.getElementById("t4").value;
                if(fname.length<5||fname.length>15)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Invalid firstname, must be 5 - 15 characters!")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample11").innerHTML = fname;

                }

            var lname = document.getElementById("t5").value;
                if(lname.length<5||lname.length>15)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Invalid lastname, must be 5 - 15 characters!")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample12").innerHTML = lname;

                }

            int age = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
            if(age < 18)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Minors not allowed.")
            }
            else
                {                   
                    document.getElementById("sample4").innerHTML = age;

                }
            var email = document.getElementById("t7").value;
                if(email.length < 8 || email.length > 50)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid Email, must be 8 - 50 characters!")
                document.getElementById("sample2").innerHTML="*";
            }
            else
            {                   

                sub=true;
            }
            var lotnum = document.getElementById("t8a").value;
                if(lotnum.length<3||lotnum.length>10)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Location Invalid.")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample13").innerHTML = lotnum;

                }

            var sub = document.getElementById("t8b").value;
                if(sub.length<5||sub.length>10)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Location Invalid.")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample14").innerHTML = sub;

                }

            var city = document.getElementById("t8c").value;
                if(city.length<5||city.length>10)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Location Invalid.")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample15").innerHTML = city;

                }

            var country = document.getElementById("t9").value;
                if(country.length<3||country.length>30)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Location Invalid.")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = country;

                }

            int area = parseInt(document.getElementById("t10a").value);
                if(area.length<3||area.length>8)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Invalid Area Code, must be 3 - 8 digits!")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = area;

                }
            int telnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("t10b").value);
                if(telnum.length<10||telnum.length>12)
                {
                sub=false;
                    alert("Invalid Number!")
                }
            else
                {                       
                    document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = telnum;

                }
            if(sub==false)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        </script>

    <center>
    <form method = "post" action = "insert.php" onSubmit="return getText()">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t1" type="text" id="t1"><span id="sample">
    </span><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t2" type="password" id="t2"><span id="sample2">
    </span><br></td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Re-type Password:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t3" type="password" id="t3"><span id="sample3">
    </span><br></td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Firstname:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t4" type="text" id="t4"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Lastname:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t5" type="text" id="t5"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t6" type="text" id="t6"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t7" type="email" id="t7"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t8a" id="t8a"><br></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t8b" id="t8b"><br></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="t8c" id="t8c"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Lot/Block#</td>
        <td>Brgy/Subd</td>
        <td>City/Municipality</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td colspan="3"><input name="t9" type="text" id="t9"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Contact#:</td>
        <td><input name="t10a" type="text" id="t10a"><br></td>
        <td><input name="t10b" type="text" id="t10b"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Area Code</td>
        <td>Number<td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br>
    <button type="submit" onClick="getText()">Submit</button><br><br>
    <p id="log">
    </p>
    </form>
    </center>
    </body>
```

***and the codes for my Database:***

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if($db){
            mysql_select_db("user1",$db);
            $username = $_POST['t1'];
            $password = $_POST['t3'];
            $firstname = $_POST['t4'];
            $lastname = $_POST['t5'];
            $age = $_POST['t6'];
            $email = $_POST['t7'];
            $lot = $_POST['t8a'];
            $sub = $_POST['t8b'];
            $city = $_POST['t8c'];
            $country = $_POST['t9'];
            $area = $_POST['t10a'];
            $num = $_POST['t10b'];

                if(mysql_query("insert into regform(username,password,firstname,lastname,age,email,lot,sub,city,country,area,num) values('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname','$age','$email','$lot','$sub','$city','$country','$area','$num')"))
                {
                    echo "Register Successful. Click <a href='index.html'> Here </a> to return";
                    }
                else
                {
                    echo "Registration Failed".mysql_error();
                }
}
    else{
        echo "Cannot Connect in Database!";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: what is not working? Are you seeing any error messages? Do you have error reporting turned on for your application ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? check may be you missed `return` in javascript code.

Comment: boolean sub = true;? How about var sub = true;

Comment: Please consider not using the 'mysql' extension for PHP. It's deprecated. Use PDO or Mysqli. And look into protecting from sql injection.

Comment: @Maximus2012, user3763227 the alert messages are not working from the javascripts, I forgot to add semicolon after each alert. but its working now. alert messages working now. -

bobdye, I change it to var sub = true; thanks

Shane - thank you i''l study that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing ; after each alert

try this code

```
<html>
<center><h1>Register Below</h1></center>


    <body>
    <br/>
<script>
    function getText()
    {
        var sub = true ;
        var name = document.getElementById("t1").value;
        if(name.length < 8 || name.length > 50)
        {
        sub=false;
            alert("Invalid Username, must be 8 - 10 characters!");
            document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML="*";
        }
        else
        {                   
            document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = name;

        }

        var pass = document.getElementById("t2").value;
        if(pass.length < 8 || pass.length > 50)
        {
        sub=false;
            alert("Invalid Password, must be 8 - 10 characters!");
            document.getElementById("sample2").innerHTML="*";
        }
        else
        {                   

            sub=true;
        }

        var rpass = document.getElementById("t3").value;
        if(rpass !== pass)
        {
        sub=false;
            alert("Password dont match!");
            document.getElementById("sample3").innerHTML="*";
        }
        else
        {   
            sub=true;
        }

        var fname = document.getElementById("t4").value;
            if(fname.length<5||fname.length>15)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid firstname, must be 5 - 15 characters!");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample11").innerHTML = fname;

            }

        var lname = document.getElementById("t5").value;
            if(lname.length<5||lname.length>15)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid lastname, must be 5 - 15 characters!");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample12").innerHTML = lname;

            }

        var age = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
        if(age < 18)
        {
        sub=false;
            alert("Minors not allowed.");
        }
        else
            {                   
                document.getElementById("sample4").innerHTML = age;

            }
        var email = document.getElementById("t7").value;
            if(email.length < 8 || email.length > 50)
        {
        sub=false;
            alert("Invalid Email, must be 8 - 50 characters!");
            document.getElementById("sample2").innerHTML="*";
        }
        else
        {                   

            sub=true;
        }
        var lotnum = document.getElementById("t8a").value;
            if(lotnum.length<3||lotnum.length>10)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Location Invalid.");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample13").innerHTML = lotnum;

            }

        var sub = document.getElementById("t8b").value;
            if(sub.length<5||sub.length>10)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Location Invalid.");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample14").innerHTML = sub;

            }

        var city = document.getElementById("t8c").value;
            if(city.length<5||city.length>10)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Location Invalid.");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample15").innerHTML = city;

            }

        var country = document.getElementById("t9").value;
            if(country.length<3||country.length>30)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Location Invalid.");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = country;

            }

        var area = parseInt(document.getElementById("t10a").value);
            if(area.length<3||area.length>8)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid Area Code, must be 3 - 8 digits!")
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = area;

            }
        var telnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("t10b").value);
            if(telnum.length<10||telnum.length>12)
            {
            sub=false;
                alert("Invalid Number!");
            }
        else
            {                       
                document.getElementById("sample16").innerHTML = telnum;

            }
        if(sub === false)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    </script>

<center>
<form method = "post" action = "insert.php">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t1" type="text" id="t1"><span id="sample">
</span><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t2" type="password" id="t2"><span id="sample2">
</span><br></td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Re-type Password:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t3" type="password" id="t3"><span id="sample3">
</span><br></td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Firstname:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t4" type="text" id="t4"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Lastname:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t5" type="text" id="t5"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t6" type="text" id="t6"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t7" type="email" id="t7"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t8a" id="t8a"><br></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t8b" id="t8b"><br></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="t8c" id="t8c"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Lot/Block#</td>
    <td>Brgy/Subd</td>
    <td>City/Municipality</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Country:</td>
    <td colspan="3"><input name="t9" type="text" id="t9"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Contact#:</td>
    <td><input name="t10a" type="text" id="t10a"><br></td>
    <td><input name="t10b" type="text" id="t10b"><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Area Code</td>
    <td>Number<td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<button type="submit" onClick="getText()">Submit</button><br><br>
<p id="log">
</p>
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you bud! I was confuse with the { and ; :D